# What does $\min\sum\dots$ indicate?

Tags: notation

What does "min" indicate infront of a sigma sign?

> $$\min \sum_{e\in E} c_e x_e$$

Source: https://www.math.unipd.it/~luigi/courses/metmodoc1718/m08.01.TSPexact.en.pdf

Comment: We need more context, the way it's written makes no sense. Please explain what's $E$, $c_e$ and $x_e$ also is there anything below the minimum? Anyway the fact that $\min$ comes before the $\sum$ shouldn't make much difference it is still a minimum of numbers, I guess the numbers are somehow obtained by applying the $\sum$.

Answer (score 2):

The $c_e$ are some constants, the $x_e$ are variables that satisfy some constraints and you are minimizing the sum $\sum_{e\in E} c_e x_e$ over all feasible choices of the $x_e$.

Comment: What does it mean to minimize the sum over all feasible choices?

Comment: Each feasible choice (i.e. choice of the $x_e$ satisfying all constraints) gives you one value of the sum. You want to find the smallest value you can get.